# Access object class using a variable

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript - access object member when identifier string is stored in a var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349411/javascript-access-object-member-when-identifier-string-is-stored-in-a-var)
>   [javascript object, access variable property name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255472/javascript-object-access-variable-property-name)

I define an object:

```
var TitlePrice = new Object();
TitlePrice.noEdit   = 1;
TitlePrice.BW       = 2;
TitlePrice.PicPaint = 3;
```

Now I define a variable, e.g.:

```
var curren="BW";
```

How can I access TitlePrice.BW using `current` variable?, e.g.:

```
TitlePrice.$current
```

Comment: javascript. `var` does not exist in Java.

Comment: Did you try with TitlePrice[current]?!

Answer (score 1):

Use the array access notation.

```
var a = {};
a.BW = 2;

var b = 'BW';
a[b] === 2
```

Comment: yes, this is what i tried to do

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  But,

```
var curren="BW";
```

is creating a variable and assigning the string "BW" to it.

Also,

```
TitlePrice.$current
```

will return undefined because you are not defining a property on your object named $current.  If you want the value of TitlePrice.BW to be assigned to the variable curren, you will need to  do something like this:

```
var curren = TitlePrice.BW;
```